# Java rest webservice with jersey exception

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey, web.xml

Hi i have the following webservice in java.

LifeEvent.java:

```
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("LifeEventService")
public class LifeEvent {

    // @GET here defines, this method will method will process HTTP GET
    // requests.
    @GET
    // @Path here defines method level path. Identifies the URI path that a
    // resource class method will serve requests for.
    @Path("/place/{numPlaces}")
    // @Produces here defines the media type(s) that the methods
    // of a resource class can produce.
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    // @PathParam injects the value of URI parameter that defined in @Path
    // expression, into the method.
    public String xPlaces(@PathParam("numPlaces") int numPlaces) {

        // String name = i;
        // return "<User>" + "<Name>" + /*name +*/ "</Name>" + "</User>";
        String xmlFile = "";
        xmlFile = "<Place>" + "<Location>" + "<Name>" + "Campo Grande, Lisboa"
                + "</Name>" + "<Picture>" + "<Description>"
                + "Last day of school kakakaka" + "</Description>" + "<Image>"
                + "12182621051540x13" + "</Image>" + "</Picture>" + "<People>"
                + "<Name>" + "Fábio Santos" + "</Name>" + "<Relation>"
                + "Amigo" + "</Relation>" + "</People>" + "<People>" + "<Name>"
                + "José Carilho" + "</Name>" + "<Relation>" + "Amigo"
                + "</Relation>" + "</People>" + "</Location>" + "<Place>";
        return xmlFile;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/place/{begin}/to/{end}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String getPlaceToPlace(@PathParam("begin") int begin,
            @PathParam("end") int end) {

        // String name = i;
        // return "<User>" + "<Name>" + /*name +*/ "</Name>" + "</User>";
        return "";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/people/{type}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String xPeople(@PathParam("type") String type) {

        // String name = i;
        // return "<User>" + "<Name>" + /*name +*/ "</Name>" + "</User>";
        return "";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/people/{begin}/to/{end}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String getPeopleToPeople(@PathParam("begin") int begin,
            @PathParam("end") int end) {

        // String name = i;
        // return "<User>" + "<Name>" + /*name +*/ "</Name>" + "</User>";
        return "";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/people/{numPeople}/important")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String getPeopleByImportance(@PathParam("numPeople") int numPeople) {

        // String name = i;
        // return "<User>" + "<Name>" + /*name +*/ "</Name>" + "</User>";
        return "";
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/people/{numPictures}/important")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String getPicturesByImportance(
            @PathParam("numPictures") int numPictures) {

        // String name = i;
        // return "<User>" + "<Name>" + /*name +*/ "</Name>" + "</User>";
        return "";
    }

}
```

and the following web.xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5"> 
    <display-name>RememberMeServer</display-name> 
    <servlet> 
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name> 
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class> 
    <init-param> 
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name> 
    <param-value>autobiographical.aid.webservices</param-value> 
    </init-param> 
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping> 
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name> 
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping> 
    </web-app>
```

I am using tomcat 7 to run this. And i use Jersey to make stuff happen. I get a error message when i run this on the browser. `http://localhost:8181/RememberMeServer/rest/LifeEventService/place/10`

```
 Exception report

message Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey REST Service threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
root cause

com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:795)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:790)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:491)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:321)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can you guys please help me. I was following this tutorial http://java.dzone.com/articles/restful-web-services-java. the only thing different from mine is that i use port 8181 and that is correct i made it work with the tutorial but not with my current version and i dont know why.

**EDIT:**

After some more tests it seems that the last two methods are the problem i think its the way the path is set. but i am still not able to figure out why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was the set of the path in that particular web service has i said in the edit.

Replacing it for another one that didn't had that problem solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to the initialization of the Jersey packages through param name and param value. Your url looks perfect.

**Param value should contain the valid package name.**

Make sure the `LifeEvent` class exists in this package  (autobiographical.aid.webservices)

That resolves the issue.

Comment: It is inside that package. i dont know why this is happening. It should work.